# Collect web data using Simple HTML Dom from multiple pages

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I used the below code and successfully collected the data from a specific page as follows:

```
    include 'simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php';

    $html = file_get_html('http://test.com/file/1209i0329/');

    // Find all article blocks
    foreach($html->find('div.Content') as $file) {
        $item['date']     = $file->find('id.article-date', 0)->plaintext;
        $item['location']    = $file->find('id.article-location', 0)->plaintext;
        $item['price'] = $file->find('div.article', 0)->plaintext;
        $files[] = $item;
    }

    print_r($files);
```

The code works well for `http://test.com/file/1209i0329.php`, but my goal is to collect data from all pages starting with `http://test.com/file/` on this domain (For example, `http://test.com/file/1209i0329/`, `http://test.com/file/120dnkj329/`, and etc). Is there a solution to overcome this problem using `simle_html_dom`?

Comment: do you want to search thru the http? maybe you can scandir on an absolute path

Comment: @kevinabelita, assume I want to get the data from `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/`, can I scan it thru http?

Comment: if you really cant use absolute paths, you could make an array of the urls you need to search, then loop then, under the loop is your current code, and of course feed it with the value

Answer (score 3):

I dont know where you would search your files (same domain, or outside), you may need to loop an array containing the urls of what you want to search.

Consider this example:

```
include 'simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php';

// most likely this process will take some time

$files = array();
$urls = array(
    'http://test.com/file/1209i0329/',
    'http://test.com/file/120dnkj329/',
    'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/',
);

foreach($urls as $url) {

    $html = file_get_html($url);

    // Find all article blocks
    foreach($html->find('div.Content') as $file) {
        $item['date']     = $file->find('id.article-date', 0)->plaintext;
        $item['location']    = $file->find('id.article-location', 0)->plaintext;
        $item['price'] = $file->find('div.article', 0)->plaintext;
        $files[] = $item;
    }

}

print_r($files);
```